# 'splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, deprecated

I'm currently updating some old apps and I'm getting this warning.
Sorry in advance if it's an obvious fix. I can't find exactly what to do online.

Warning:

> 'splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use splitViewController:willChangeToDisplayMode: and displayModeButtonItem instead

My code section is:

```
if (!isLandscape) {
    [self splitViewController:splitViewController willHideViewController:master withBarButtonItem:button forPopoverController:popover];
}
else if (isLandscape) {
    [self splitViewController:splitViewController willShowViewController:master invalidatingBarButtonItem:button];
}
```

Comment: The warning message _tells_ you what the problem and what to do about it, so what's the question?

Comment: Hey matt, sorry I'm not sure how to implement it in my code, thats all :[

Comment: Well, the code makes no sense. You have no business _calling_ `splitViewController:willHideViewController` or any of the methods mentioned here. They are events that Cocoa uses to call into _your_ code. You must never call them yourself; they are not yours to call.

Comment: sorry Its not my original code, its something I'm helping a school to update for a quiz app.

Comment: I understand perfectly, but you can't "fix" that code: it's doing something that must never be done. You're going to have to undertake some kind of complete rewrite.